# Facebook module positioning in safari mobile

Tags: css, ipad, mobile-safari

I am having trouble positioning a facebook follow button in the footer of a site I am building. It works great on the desktop but on mobile safari it positions to the left when it should stay right. I have tried floats that didn't seem to work either. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Here is the link:
http://andreascharalambous.com/newsite/

Here is the markup with a base of twitter bootstrap:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=311803262255643";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="fb-follow" data-href="https://www.facebook.com//pages/AndreasCharalambouscom/275009314345" data-colorscheme="light" data-layout="button" data-show-faces="false"></div>
    <div class="copy">&copy andreas charalambous 2014 - All Rights Reserved</div>
</div>

footer .copy{
    padding:10px;
    font-weight:100;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}

footer .fb-follow{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    right:30px;
    display:block;
    width:50px;
}

footer .container{
    border-top:1px solid #ccc;
    margin-top:35px;
    position:relative;
}
```

There seems to be something going on with the code facebook injects into the page after load. Good luck! I have no idea...

Comment: Copy the relevant code into the question, otherwise this question will be useless when your site changes in the future.

Comment: In order to troubleshoot this you should apply border(s) to the footer and the body, to see what *they* are doing.  I have found sometimes the body does not stretch full width.  Then, when you view on the iPad, you may find the body (or footer) is not stretching full width, which is a completely different problem...

Comment: RE: @cale_b - you can do that in dev tools very quickly. That is what I did.

Comment: @sherrifderek - how do you access dev tools on iPad? Or are you talking on desktop Safari - will it emulate iPad?

Comment: I've added widths with floats and now even absolute positioning and its acting very strange. I'll post the code

Comment: I would make a red square or something... and see if you can get it to do what you want independent of the FB thing. Then if that works, shove the button in there.

Comment: Yup its the facebook module. There is something going on with the code it creates after load...